# in HBase what will happen if a single row size exceeds region max size?

Tags: split, row, hbase, region

I know that if region size exceeds the configured max size, HBase will split it into 2 regions, and seems that 1 row is only located in 1 region. So what will happen if row size exceeds the configured max region size?

For example, if I have a row which has 100 columns, and each column contains 3M bytes, so totally there are 300M bytes for this row. and max region size is set to 256M, so what will happens for this? 
Maybe I can't insert such a row successfully?

Comment: Why would you want to set a region to only  256M regions should be in the gigabytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HBase splits are done on row boundaries. If a row happens to be larger than the region size, it will not be split.